# android studio overview menu icon is missing

Tags: android, android-layout

i set up a Basicactivity to test the menus. I tried to setup a secound item with icon, but the icon is not visible.

menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.mogri.menu.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="99"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

and activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.mogri.menu.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The icon is saved in the directory drawable with the name logout.png (128x128).

Comment: Which part of `app:showAsAction="never"` makes you think an icon will display?

Comment: And where is the Java code that inflates the menu into the Toolbar?

Comment: try `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` for your icon